# Member detection using void_t

Tags: c++, c++14

For member detection in C++14 I used code based on the example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t), but it does no seem to work.

A complete example:

```
#include <string>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename, typename = void> class HasMember_substr : public std::false_type {};
template <typename T> class HasMember_substr<T, void_t<typename T::substr>> : public std::true_type {};

template <typename, typename = void> class HasMember_fff : public std::false_type {};
template <typename T> class HasMember_fff<T, void_t<typename T::fff>> : public std::true_type {};

static_assert(HasMember_substr<std::string>::value, "");
static_assert(!HasMember_fff<std::string>::value, "");

int main() { return 0; }
```

Compiled using `clang++ --std=c++14 test.cpp` on OS X, compiler version (`clang++ --version`): `Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`

The second assert succeeds, but the first fails. Why? I have also tried using `decltype(T::substr)` instead of `typename T::subset`, with the same result.

Comment: `T::substr` is not the same as `T{}.substr`

Comment: Is `substr` an overloaded function in your implementation?  (It's allowed to be.)

Comment: You have copied an example of testing for a type, and expect the same code to work for testing for a member function. That's obviously not going to work. `std::string::substr` is not a type, so `typename T::substr` is obviously nonsense. You should have copied the example that tests for pre-increment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking for `T::substr` is not the same as looking for a member function called `substr`. [gcc.godbolt.org example](https://goo.gl/5yfMfU)

You can check if a member function exists by using [`std::declval<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) and using [decltype](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to get the return type of the member function.

If the member function exists, `decltype(...)` will be a well-formed expression and will not trigger SFINAE - therefore the the `static_assert` will work correctly.

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename, typename = void> 
class HasMember_substr : public std::false_type {};

template <typename T> 
class HasMember_substr<T, void_t<
     decltype(std::declval<T>().substr(1, 1))>
> : public std::true_type {};

static_assert(HasMember_substr<std::string>::value, "");

int main() { return 0; }
```

Note that `decltype(std::declval<T>().substr(1, 1))` checks whether `T` has a `substr` member that can be called with arguments `1, 1`. *(This **is not guaranteed** to be a member function, it could also be a functor data member, for example.)*

---

As said by AndyG in the comments, another possible approach is using `decltype` to "validate" the type of a member function pointer.

Example:

```
HasMember_substr<T, void_t< decltype(&T::substr)>
```

Note that this will not work if the name `substr` is overloaded, and it [is not guaranteed to work with any type in the standard library](http://eel.is/c++draft/member.functions#2).

Comment: I might simplify as `HasMember_substr<T, void_t<
     decltype(&T::substr)>`

Comment: @AndyG this won't work if name `substr` is overloaded

Comment: Ah, I see. The example on cppreference was about a member *type*, not member function. decltype(&T::substr) is good enough for now, overloads are not of a big concern (yet).

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Did not consider that!

Comment: "this will not work if the name substr is overloaded"...and so [is not guaranteed to work with any type in the standard library](http://eel.is/c++draft/member.functions#2).

Comment: To be precise, the version with `decltype(std::declval<T>().substr(0, 0))` doesn't check whether `T` has a `substr` member function. It checks whether `T` has a `substr` member that can be called with arguments `0, 0`. That's something different. For instance, it allows `substr` to be a functor data member. Another example: it doesn't allow `substr` to be a member function taking no arguments. That's good, probably closer to what the OP wants, but it may be helpful to post more clearly in your answer what it's doing. Also, I suggest `1, 1` to rule out interpretation as null pointer constants.

Comment: @hvd: thanks for the suggestions, editing my answer.

Comment: I don't think hvd's point needs to be highlighted with **Caution**. It's an interesting fact and worth pointing out, but there is nothing to be cautious about. The point is that testing `decltype(std::declval<T>().substr(1, 1))` works in all cases that you care about, you don't need to care if it's a function or not (and you don't need to be cautious).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant too, you're doing the right thing, you're doing exactly what makes sense, so no need to treat my comment as a warning. :)