# Ambiguous Function Overloads [e.g. max()]

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, templates, overloading

Is it possible to overload a function in C++ that has similar, yet different template signatures.

Consider the max() function.  What if I want a `max()` function that can take in a pair of the following three options: `int`, `*int` range, `int` iterator range.

The STL has this functionality split into two functions:

- [max()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/)
- [max_element()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/)

So can you or can you not achieve this behavior in C++ and if so how?

Edit: this would make `max(vec.begin(), vec.end());` and `max(vec[0], vec[1]);` compile successfully and find the max of the range and the max of the two passed objects.  I personally think that it is not possible otherwise the two functions would be combined in the STL, but I would confirmation that it isn't doable.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Have you tried it?  Where did you run into trouble?

Comment: as long as the function calls do not interfere with functions calls with the same name you shouldnt have any issues with overloading

Comment: You can't implement a function that looks like this `int max( const int * p );`  because there is no way of telling how many ints  `p` points to, so you would want something like `int max( const int * begin, const int * end );` and similar for iterators.

Comment: @aschepler http://cpp.sh/8grre error: redefinition of 'template<class Iter> Iter Algorithm::maximum(Iter, Iter)'

Comment: @ChrisHutchison but they do interfere because they have the same signature, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Post the code that has the same signatures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the overloads are ambiguous because you didn't restrict them. How is the compiler supposed to know that the first one shouldn't be used for iterators?

The answer is simple, you have to tell it. Luckily, the standard defines [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) which you can query for all kinds of information about the iterator type you passed to it - as long as it is an iterator.

The last point here is key: If `std::iterator_tags<T>` doesn't have a nested typedef `iterator_category`, then `T` is not an iterator. Therefore we can use [member detection using `void_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402126/member-detection-using-void-t) to define a custom trait that checks if a given type is an iterator.

In code, it looks like this:

```
// C++17 void_t
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator : std::false_type {
};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, void_t<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>> : std::true_type {
};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto is_iterator_v = is_iterator<T>::value;
```

Here I've also defined the constexpr variable `is_iterator_v` for convenience.

We can use this trait in combination with `std::enable_if` to selectively disable one of the two previously ambiguous overloads based on whether or not a type `T` is an iterator. To to so, simply replace the template declaration `template <typename T>` by `template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator_v<T>, int> = 0>` and `template <typename T, std::enable_if<!is_iterator_v<T>, int> = 0>` respectively.

Putting everything together, the code should look similar to this:

```
// C++17 void_t
template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator : std::false_type {
};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, void_t<typename   std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>> : std::true_type {
};

template <typename T>
constexpr auto is_iterator_v = is_iterator<T>::value;

template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_iterator_v<T>, int> = 0>
constexpr T maximum(T a, T b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

template<typename Iter, std::enable_if_t<is_iterator_v<Iter>, int> = 0>
constexpr Iter maximum(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    if(begin == end) {
        return end;
    }
    auto max = begin;
    for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
        if(*begin > *max) {
            max = begin;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

You can also find the working example on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MXUNgjAVIES3zgLv).